# split a string at first occurrence of html tag

Tags: php, html, regex, string, split

How can I split a string into 2 variables at first occurrence of a specific html tag (section in this case)?

```
$str = 'some text, <b>some text</b> <section class="first">abc</sextion><section class="second">abc</section> some text';

$first = 'some text, <b>some text</b> ';
$second = '<section class="first">abc</sextion><section class="second">abc</section> some text';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_split`

```
preg_split('~(?=<section\b)~', $str, 2)
```

Third paramter `2` specifies the no of items would be returned after splitting. So this would give you only two parts.

Comment: The third parameter must be 2, not 1.

Comment: I think the constant (`PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE`) is a bit more meaningful than just `2` : ]

Comment: Why? It won't remove the space which exists before the `<section`